# (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor) with the same ID "16" already exists. Error keeps showing in Health Monitor Suite

Tags: debugging, bug, id

(Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor) with the same ID "16" already exists. Error keeps showing in Health Monitor Suite.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran in to this problem.
It was caused by duplicate newsletter subscribers.
Because of this the MySQL join resulted in two customer records being returned with the same ID when searching in the customer repository via the API.

Answer (score 1):

Please check UI Grid Component column data.

and kindly check if you are saving new customer with static ID or dynamic ID.

Generally, This error comes when you tried to create new instance of the customer with same id.

If this helps then HIT LIKE.

Enjoy your coding :)

Hiren Patel

Comment: Hi @Hiren, Where would I check that at? Ui Grid Component column data?

Comment: First you need to identify that from where this error is coming. then if there is a loop of saving customer instance there you have to check

Answer (score 1):

So looking more into this. From what Len said above it was duplicate newsletter subscriber with the same ID but subscribed to different store views. Also a bug with Magento. More information below and the answer on how to fix here and a fix will be available in Magento2.4.3 or 2.4.4 I believe.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31814

What I did to fix and remove error was remove all duplicate subscribers out of store number 2 from database on our live site. Store 2 is a store that we are not using anymore.  It seems the error shows up when a duplicate email address exists, even though they are on different store views by Website. So I deleted every duplicate and the error does not show up anymore!